# OxyPlot CandleStickAndVolumeSeries Namespace not found

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, oxyplot

I'm trying to create a CandlestickAndVolumeSeries with Oxyplot.Xamarin.Android. I have already created a CandlestickSeries which works fine.

So now I have taken the CandleStickAndVolumeSeries-Example from the Oxyplot-Example-Browser like I did with the CandleStickSeries and copied it into the same class where I'm already using the CandlestickSeries, but I get an error message "Namespace not found".

I am using OxyPlot.Xamarin.Android Version 2015.1.721-alpha, with Xamarin Studio 5.9.4 (build 5).

This is the line where I get the error message:

```
        var candleStickAndVolumeSeries1 = new CandleStickAndVolumeSeries();
```

For me, it seems like I have done everything right and just the             CandleStickAndVolumeSeries-Class is missing. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I have now been trying to get the newest version from Nuget, but I can't add it to my project. I get an error message: "Das Default-Element erfordert ein nicht leeres Extension-Attribut. Zeile 1, Position 378." 
In english it should bee something like "The default element requires a non-empty extension attribute . Line 1 , position 378."

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what has happened with your setup but I added OxyPlot.Xamarin.Android Version 2015.1.943-alpha and it has the class `CandleStickAndVolumeSeries` and builds fine.

I would try to update your package to this version or replace the old package with the new package.

Also make sure you are using 
`using OxyPlot.Series;`

Comment: Thanks for your response. So at the moment it seems like there is messed up something else. When I'm trying to add the new package from Nuget I get an error message. I will add this to my question.